# Evaluate parameter in symfit model

Tags: python, symfit

I am using symfit for fitting of two NMR data set simultaneously.I defined a cut-off gaussian distribution on one of the parameter. I summerized my explanation in the following simplified example:

```
import symfit as sf
from symfit import parameters, variables, Fit, Model, Ge
from symfit.core.minimizers import BFGS, BasinHopping, NelderMead, DifferentialEvolution
from symfit import GradientModel, CallableModel
xd= [1.1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 14, 19, 25, 32, 44]
yd= [5.5, 8, 11, 14, 18, 22, 28, 35,45, 69, 110]
pi=3.14
x, y = variables('x, y')
a = sf.Parameter('a',value=3)
b = sf.Parameter('b',value=0.7)
sigma= sf.Parameter('sigma',value=0.7)
res=0
norm=0
for i in range(1,5):
    atemp= (a + ((i-1)*3*sigma/2))
    if atemp < 0:
        atemp = 0
    gauss= sf.exp(-(atemp-a)**2/(2*(sigma**2)))/sf.sqrt(2*pi*(sigma**2))
    res= res+ gauss* (atemp * x + b) 
    norm= norm + gauss
    if i == 4:
        firstres= res
        firstnorm= norm
        res=0
        norm=0

funfit = CallableModel({y: (firstres/firstnorm)})

fit = Fit(funfit, x= xd, y=yd, minimizer=[NelderMead, BFGS])
fit_result = fit.execute()
print(" Best-Fit Parameters: ", fit_result)
```

I need to check "atemp" be positive because negetive values does not have any physical meaning. I know that "atemp" is a parameter and is an expression but I need to get the value of this parameter. I tried atemp.evalf() and it does not work. I get such an error:
"TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational"

Comment: You could implement it as a constraint, see e.g. [this example](https://symfit.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/ex_piecewise.html?highlight=constraint). And please use `np.pi`, you damn near gave me a heart attack with `pi = 3.14` :P. Lastly, symfit has a predefined Gaussian model you could use: https://symfit.readthedocs.io/en/stable/module_docs.html?highlight=gaussian#symfit.distributions.Gaussian.

Comment: And if `a` itself can also not be negative then you could also give it a bound: `a = sf.Parameter('a',value=3, min=0.0)`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. May be I could not explain the problem clearly. actually using a piecewise model can be tricky way but in my case x is not a series of number. in my example you can see that we want to fit a line with parameter a , b , sigma which is the standard deviation of a. so if a would be near zero and sigma would be braod enough we have some negative values in atemp(which is distribution of a).

Comment: these negetaive values are unphysical in my particular problem (sometimes these negetive values would be hidden in the sigma and a which is mean value in gaussian distribution. both of them could be positive but we consider some negetive values in distribution of a.). to avoid this issue I need to check the atemp value. based on your suggestion I can use a piecewise model for gauss function but we should define it like this:

Comment: ``temp , gauss = variables ('temp, gauss')
    med, sigma = parameters('med, sigma')
    gauss1 = 0
    gauss2= sf.exp(-0.5*((temp-med)/sigma)**2)/(sf.sqrt(2*np.pi)* sigma)
    gaussian= CallableModel({gauss: Piecewise((gauss1, temp<=0), (gauss2, temp>0))})``here for evaluating the model to give me the value, 'temp' should be equal to 'atemp'. 'atemp' is not a number, it is an expression contains of "a" and "sigma". based on this, it is not possible to be checked with a number in a piecewise model. because of that I get this error:"TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational"

Comment: Hi @farhad, I think you misunderstood my answer. I'm not suggesting that you should use a Piecewise function, merely that you should implement this as a constraint for your fit. The page I linked gives an example of how to implement constraints using symfit. I think you should try to adapt this example to your problem and that would do the trick. Another example can be found here in the docs: https://symfit.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fitting_types.html#constrained-least-squares-fit

Comment: @tBuLi, Thanks a lot for the reply.Actually the explanation of my model is quite difficult. So I just summerize what exactly need. I need to get the value of a defined parameter for a fitting model during iteration. for each iteration. Is there any way to get this?